# Odds of coin flipping heads 10 times in a row

Tags: python

I can easily find the number of heads out of 100 and the chances of coin flipping heads out of 100 flips. That code is below.  However, I can't figure out how to easily get the odds of coin flipping heads 10 times *in a row*.

```
import random

n = int(input("Enter the number of flips: "))

sum = 0
heads = 0
tails = 0
for n in range(1, n + 1):
    number = random.randrange(0,2)
    if number == 0:
        heads += 1
    else:
        tails += 1
    sum += number
    odds = sum / n


print("No. of heads: ", heads)
print("No. of tails: ", tails)
print("Odds: ", odds)
```

Comment: You are aware of `(1/2)^10`?

Comment: `odds = sum / n` should probably not be indented there. And you overwrote the `n` variable with the loop counter

Comment: @schwobaseggl: I think OP needs to simulate the flips, not compute the *expected* value.

Comment: @Prune You are probably right. Irhad, Do 10 flips a large number (>10**5) of times. Then divide the number of times you got all 10 heads by that number.

Comment: @cricket_007 You are right. Shouldn't have indented the sum / n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flip the coin 10 times, but only report success if they *all* come up heads.  Do this with reverse logic: if any one comes up tails, set your flag to False.

```
all_heads = True
for i in range(10):
    number = random.randrange(0,2)
    if number != 0:
        all_heads = False
```

Or, more succinctly

```
all_heads = True
for i in range(10):
    all_heads &= random.randrange(0,2) == 0
```

... and even more pythonic

```
all_heads = all(random.randrange(0,2) == 0 for i in range(10))
```

Whichever you choose, you'll need to do it enough times to approximate a statistical universe.  Since you expect only one success in 1024 trials, you'll want on the order of 10,000 - 100,000 trials.  Count the number of successes, divide by the number of trials.  You already know how to do that part.

---

**SPOILER:**

Given the length of the run of heads, **n**, and the number of trials, this reduces to

```
print (sum(all(random.randrange(0,2) for _ in range(n)) \
          for _ in range(trials))                       \
       / float(trials) )
```

Welcome to Python.  :-)

Comment: In the first snippet, when `number != 0`, not only should `all_heads` be set to `False`, you should also exit the `for` loop early—especially if you going to simulate doing it a very larger number of times.

Comment: You're correct.  I left that out for simplicity, and a little consistency with the **all** method later.

Comment: Didn't think about using the reverse logic, but seems to be working after I added the part of the code you mentioned. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: @Prune the `all` method [exits the for loop as soon as one element does not satisfy the condition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L275)

Comment: I'm aware of that.  I'm trying to keep the steps intellectually accessible to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

One experiment would now amount to ten flips. You have to repeat that often enough to get your desired outcome (10 heads) sufficiently often:

```
import random

n = int(input("Enter the number of tries: "))  # 1 try = 10 flips
ten_head_count = 0

for _ in range(n):
    if all(x==0 for x in (random.randrange(0,2) for _ in range(10))):
        ten_head_count += 1

print("No. of ten heads: ", ten_head_count)
print("No. of tries: ", n)
print("Odds: ", ten_head_count/n)
```

Comment: Looks like a really easy and nice way to do this. Thanks